# How to create single view of multiple tables in multiple databases in another database?

Tags: mysql, database, view

How to create single view of multiple tables in multiple databases in another database?

I have multiple tables in multiple databases having same column structure. I want to create single view for all those tables in another database?

Is it possible? if it is possible how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are on different servers, the answer is no. If they're on the same server, yes, and the following is a template for doing so:

```
CREATE VIEW [view name] AS
    SELECT [columns]
    FROM [db1].[table1] t1
        JOIN [db2].[table2] t2 ON [join condition]
```

The key is to explicitly define the database for each table that is part of the query.

Comment: Definitely `CREATE VIEW`, but probably `UNION ALL` over `JOIN`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams You're right: UNION ALL might be preferable to JOIN depending on the specifics of the query, which aren't at all clear.